# Can we use multiple databases with Spring Boot without JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring

I want to connect to 2 mysql databases from my spring boot application but without using Spring Boot Starter Data JPA?

Comment: Juste use 2 EntityManager, eatch one with it's JDBC Connection.

Comment: Or look at JOOQ.

Comment: Zorglube, I will try your suggestion, Thanks